# How to find custom ROMs for rare android devices?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, tablet

I've recently bought a [Tesla H7](http://www.tesla.info/en/technical-specifications-h7/) tablet. Since it's a 'local' brand, I don't expect to see any updates, and I was wandering how could I find some other (cyanogen, or other) ROMs to update the software myself (currently, it's 4.2.2).

Do I search for roms that match the CPU/resolution/ram/... does it need to match every specification, or only in part?

Comment: A ROM needs to be for the **exact** device and model. If you use anything even SLIGHTLY different you will brick the device. It needs to be made for the device in question.

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) – and also at our [rom tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info).

Comment: So basically, it has to match each-and-every hardware specification to be applicable (makes sense)... if you put it in an answer I'll mark it as solved... thanks!